# In Veda mantras, who exactly is intended by the 'nah' and 'no' (us and our)?

Tags: vedas, meaning, rudram

Veda mantras/suktams almost entirely seek benedictions/blessings in plural (us, our and we) and not in singular (me and my); this is why whether in Yajur veda mantras for Agni or Indra or Rudram (namakam) & even Gayatri mantra, we see 'naH' and 'no' instead of 'mama' or 'maya' or 'mAm' or '...me' when blessings are seeked in such mantras.

Now, if a ritualistic yagnya with agni kriya is being done by a purohit for somebody, then totally understand why these mantras need to be in plural seeking for 'us' or 'our'. But if you are doing a solitary Antar-japa of these vedic mantras, whether Sri Rudram or Purusha Suktam etc. then who exactly comes under 'us' and 'we' and 'our' - just the person doing the japa, or his family too, or his town/village/city or entire humanity?

Comment: Naha in gayatri mantra explicitly refers lord buddha gge sanskrit dictionary have thesame